# Removing a Galera node from a cluster

Tags: mariadb, galera

There is a lot of documentation and mentions online for removing a node from the cluster that you simply need to do:

```
SET GLOBAL wsrep_desync = ON; 
SET GLOBAL wsrep_on = OFF;
```

However this doesn't seem to remove the node at all from the cluster, changes made on other nodes still propagate to this one and changes on the node that should be removed still propagate to the rest of the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason as I was posting this question but may be useful for someone else. Until the node that has been desynced receives some operation that causes read lock on the db it stays synced. Slightly confusing behaviour but fine once understood.